# Parse json string to json array?

Tags: java, android, json

i need help to convert json string to json array as i given below

```
{"level":[{"id":"1","name":"first","time":"00:02:00"},{"id":"2","name":"second","time":"00:03:00"},{"id":"3","name":"math","time":"00:03:00"},
{"id":"4","name":"language ","time":"00:03:00"},{"id":"5","name":"sport","time":"00:04:00"}]}
```

to use it in android studio

Comment: i try to use jsonarray(string) but it return json exception

Comment: please check my ans.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
try 
{    
    JSONObject resObject = new JSONObject("your json response");    
    JSONArray jsonArray = resObject.getJSONArray("level");        

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {  

       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

       Log.i("id", "" + jsonObject.getString("id"));
       Log.i("name","" + jsonObject.getString("name"));
       Log.i("time", "" + jsonObject.getString("time"));

   }

} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(yourresponsestring);
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("level"));


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id=jsonObject1.getString("id");
            String name=jsonObject1.getString("name");
            String time=jsonObject1.getString("time");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to convert the data to JSON:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"level\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"first\",\"time\":\"00:02:00\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"second\",\"time\":\"00:03:00\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"math\",\"time\":\"00:03:00\"}, {\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"language \",\"time\":\"00:03:00\"},{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"sport\",\"time\":\"00:04:00\"}]}");
    JSONArray level = jsonObject.getJSONArray("level");

    for (int i = 0; i < level.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject data = level.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = data.getString("id");
        String name = data.getString("name");
        String time = data.getString("time");
        Log.d("JSONDATA--->", "Data at: " + i + " " + id + ":" + name + ":" + time);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```